# SKPaymentQueue updated transactions when user is logged out

Tags: ios, subscription, storekit, skpaymenttransaction

I'm developing an application using subscriptions, and as such call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];` upon launch. This is to receive any new and pending transactions as soon as the application launches.

This works for the most part, however if the user is completely logged out of their App Store/ iTunes account (*"Settings" -> "iTunes and App Store" -> username -> "Log Out"*), it has no effect. The user is not prompted to log in or anything, and I do not receive any new transactions.

Is this intended behavior? Most information I've found online says the user should be prompted for their username/ password when adding a transaction observer. If this is intended behavior, how should I handle the situation? How would I determine the user is logged out and provide him with the necessary information needed for him to take the correct actions to resume service?

Comment: I just check the application receipt to look for renewals

Comment: @Paulw11 I do too, but I'd like to confirm with the transaction and mark that as completed if it's of significance. My application is mainly an extension, and people only switch back when it's time to check for renewals. Because this is the only chance I have to receive that transaction, I'd like to do it if possible.